# how to change the width and height of infowindow on google-maps-v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

i want to set the width and height of the infowindow using v3

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a div with desired width, height and content inside the InfoWindow using [InfoWindow.setContent()](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#InfoWindow) method.

Comment: can change the width ,but can not change the height.

Comment: @zjm1126: Are you including images without specifying their size? If so, you need to set the right attributes. If not, edit your question to include a demonstration.

Answer (score 2):

The info window will adjust its height automatically to fit all the contents, but if you want a width that is different from the standard you have to set it through the InfoWindow options.

I would recommend putting a div with a set height into the infowindow via the setContent.